# unable to read RDF triples data from file its give an exception?

Tags: java, hbase, rdf, bigdata, jena

I am using JDK 7 and  my jena library version - 2.11.1

below is my sample triples data file name RDF.nt

```
<http://sce.umkc.edu/> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Ontology> .
<http://sce.umkc.edu/> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#imports> <http://purl.uniprot.org/core/> .
<http://purl.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q6GZX4> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://purl.uniprot.org/core/Protein> .
<http://purl.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q6GZX4> <http://purl.uniprot.org/core/reviewed> <true"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean> .
<http://purl.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q6GZX4> <http://purl.uniprot.org/core/created> <2011-06-28"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date> .
<http://purl.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q6GZX4> <http://purl.uniprot.org/core/modified> <2011-07-27"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date> .
<http://purl.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q6GZX4> <http://purl.uniprot.org/core/version> <22"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int> .
<http://purl.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q6GZX4> <http://purl.uniprot.org/core/mnemonic> <001R_FRG3G" .
<http://purl.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q6GZX4> <http://purl.uniprot.org/core/citation> <http://purl.uniprot.org/citations/15165820> .
<http://sce.umkc.edu/#_5136475A5834001> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Statement> .
<http://sce.umkc.edu/#_5136475A5834001> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#subject> <http://purl.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q6GZX4> .
<http://sce.umkc.edu/#_5136475A5834001> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#predicate> <http://purl.uniprot.org/core/citation> .
```

my java code

```
public class ReadRDF {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String inputFileName = "Rdf.nt";
        // use the FileManager to find the input file
        Model model = FileManager.get().loadModel(inputFileName, null,
                "N-TRIPLES");
        model.write(System.out, "TRIPLES");

    }
}
```

error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 4, col: 91] Broken IRI (bad character: '<'): true"^^
    at org.apache.jena.riot.system.ErrorHandlerFactory$ErrorHandlerStd.fatal(ErrorHandlerFactory.java:136)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangEngine.raiseException(LangEngine.java:163)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangEngine.nextToken(LangEngine.java:106)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangNTriples.parseOne(LangNTriples.java:67)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangNTriples.runParser(LangNTriples.java:54)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangBase.parse(LangBase.java:42)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParserRegistry$ReaderRIOTFactoryImpl$1.read(RDFParserRegistry.java:142)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.process(RDFDataMgr.java:859)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.parse(RDFDataMgr.java:687)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:208)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:141)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:130)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.adapters.AdapterFileManager.readModelWorker(AdapterFileManager.java:291)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.loadModelWorker(FileManager.java:333)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.loadModel(FileManager.java:320)
    at com.jena.main.ReadRDF.main(ReadRDF.java:10)
```

Please help me to read this data and how can store RDF data in to Hbase database.

how can ignore bad character: '<' because I have more then 1 million record in my file if I going to change each record its take my long time please suggest another alternative

Comment: Where is this data from? You seem to have '<' at the start of literal like `<true"^^...` when you should have a double quote `"`. That fault is repeated throughout.

Comment: how can ignore bad character: '<' because I have more then 1 million record in my file if i going to change each record its take my long time please suggest another alternative

Comment: @jayesh The data isn't well-formed;  the best workaround is to fix the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your data that is broken, you will need to fix the errors that @user205512 already pointed out in their commend before you will be able to make any progress.

Another thing to realise is that there is no such serialisation as `N-TURTLES`, what you likely meant is `N-TRIPLES`.

Your code probably only works because Jena ignores the unknown language and detects the input format from the file extension instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is bad:

```
<true"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean>
```

is not a literal "true"^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean

There are lots of other errors for what I guess are supposed to literals.